# Invoke intent to capture a photo with Camera2

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

The code below allows you to invoke an intent to capture photos via Camera.

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

What I want to know is the code for Camera2? I already have my codes ready for the Camera2 intent, I just don't know how to redirect my button to it.

Answer (score 2):

> The code below allows you to invoke an intent to capture photos via Camera.

No. That code starts the user's choice of camera app. That can be any one of dozens (if not hundreds) of pre-installed camera apps, or any one of dozens (if not hundreds) of user-installed camera apps.

> What I want to know is the code for Camera2?

There is no `Intent` for "Camera2".

There are Java classes in `android.hardware.camera2.*` that offer a more direct API to the camera. Those are counterparts to `android.hardware.Camera`, not `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: You mean Camera2 are only applicable to MainActivity? I can't be opened by a button?

Comment: @Abegail: I mean that "Camera2" is not something that you can invoke from an `Intent`. There is nothing to "open" with `android.hardware.Camera` or the `android.hardware.camera2.*` classes.

Comment: But then, if I use the ordinary camera, I can just use the codes above and the button I have will redirect me to it. If the ordinary camera can, is it possible for `Camera2` too?

Comment: @Abegail: What do you think "`Camera2`" is? You seem to think that it is an app. It is not.

Comment: I'm politely asking if there's a way I can redirect my button to `Camera2` ?

Comment: @Abegail: And I am asking what you think `Camera2` is.